# Fortran - Usage of Variables

Tags: fortran

Once compiled, is there any difference in execution speed/efficiency to using an extra variable to reference some part of an array versus continually indexing it?  For example:

```
... some code that defines/populates "array" here ...
item3 = array(3)
subroutine1(item3, ...)
...
subroutine2(item3, ...)
...
some equation using item3
...
subroutine3(item3, ...)
... etc
```

versus

```
... some code that defines/populates "array" here ...
subroutine1(array(3), ...)
...
subroutine2(array(3), ...)
...
some equation using array(3)
...
subroutine3(array(3), ...)
... etc
```

Another example might be creating a variable that could just be skipped.  For example:

```
x = b / c
y = x + 1  ! This is the only use of x
```

vs

```
y = (b / c) + 1
```

Would these be equivalent when compiled, or would the first one be slower due to creating that variable "x"?  If you needed that value of "x" many times, then I assume the first would be quicker then since it would avoid doing the division many times.  But for only 1 or 2 uses, I'm not sure.

Comment: This is very compiler dependent.  It may be more or less efficient depending on the optimising options and the code generation.

Comment: If there is any difference it will probably be extremely small - write the code in whichever way is clearest.

Comment: Optimizing compilers can handle stuff like these, write your code to be clear.